# Android instrumentation: Pass test options using interpolation

Tags: bash, android-instrumentation

I am trying to pass some test options to my Android Instrumentation tests as below:

```
export value1="abcd"
export value2="pqrs"
export value3="xyz"

adb shell 'CLASSPATH=$(pm path androidx.test.services) app_process / \
  androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain am instrument -r -w -e \
  targetInstrumentation com.example.test/com.example.runner.CustomAndroidRunner \
  -e class com.example.TestingDemo#testWithoutApiInvocation \
  -e clearPackageData true -e debug false \
  -e myKey1 "$value1" \
  -e myKey2 "$value2" \
  -e myKey3 "$value3" \
  androidx.test.orchestrator/androidx.test.orchestrator.AndroidTestOrchestrator'
```

In my test code, I am getting empty values for `myKey(1)(2)(3)`.

As per my understanding, bash variables are not expanded inside the single quotes. So, when I included above command in double quotes, it is not running.

Is it possible to pass variable values to the tests as I am doing above?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. After debugging a bit more, I was able to get it working as below.

```
adb shell 'CLASSPATH=$(pm path androidx.test.services) app_process / \
  androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain am instrument -r -w -e \
  targetInstrumentation com.example.test/com.example.runner.CustomAndroidRunner \
  -e class com.example.TestingDemo#testWithoutApiInvocation \
  -e clearPackageData true -e debug false \
  -e myKey1' "$value1" '\
  -e myKey2' "$value2" '\
  -e myKey3' "$value3" '\
  androidx.test.orchestrator/androidx.test.orchestrator.AndroidTestOrchestrator'
```